# Search between 2 dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, search

I am trying to do a search between 2 dates. I have created an advanced search form with 2 fields, `date_from` and `date_to`. I want to use these fields to search between the dates ranges of created_at & completed_at.

I wrote a query but I get blank result (no entries) with it:

```
def search_requests
requests = Request.all

requests = requests.where("created_at > ? AND completed_at < ?", date_from, date_to)
requests = requests.where(["title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?", "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%"]) if keywords.present?
requests = requests.where(["incomplete LIKE ?", incomplete]) if incomplete.present?

return requests
end
```

Comment: @sawa i would like to know the correct syntax to carry out this search between the 2 date fields

Comment: Where does `date_from` and `date_to` actually come from? Are both instances of `Time`, `Date` or just `String`?

Comment: they are datetime field types just created for purpose of search form. @spickermann

Comment: Can you share the log entries for one example request? Especially the parameters coming in from the browser and the SQL query string generated by Rails?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `date_from` and `date_to` are `date` type otherwise convert it inito date

```
#date_to = date_to.to_date
#date_from =  date_from.to_date
```

Query -

```
requests = requests.where("created_at::date >= ? AND completed_at::date < ?", date_from, date_to)
```

Or

```
requests = requests.where("created_at >= ? AND completed_at < ?", date_from.beginning_of_day, date_to.end_of_day)
```

Comment: Thank you but i get errors on both. For the first one i get an issue with the :: and the second one it does not regcongize beginning_of_day and end_of_day. When i remove these i get NO errors but no results are displaying.

Comment: I can also confirm they are both date fields. Thanks

Comment: @kush can you show how do you form date_to and date _from?

Comment: sure i will update the question with full syntax thanks @gabbar

Comment: @Kush Still i can't see how did you form `date_from`  and `date_to `  ? from where this is coming?

Answer (score 0):

You can typecast the dates to `date` format and use as follows:

```
requests = requests.where("DATE(created_at) > ? AND DATE(completed_at) < ?", date_from, date_to)
```

it triggers like this on-rails console,

```
Request Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE (DATE(created_at) > '2019-03-03' AND DATE(completed_at) < '2019-03-09')
```